# How do I set the combobox value on a page reset?

Tags: php, webforms

When I return to a user because of errors in PHP, I can give the textboxes a value with something like `value = "<?php if(isset($_POST['abc'])){echo $_POST['abc'];}`. How do I do the equivalent with a `<select>` combobox?

Comment: i am not sure this will not able to do in php. instead of php we can use jquery cookies to solve this problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends a bit on what you mean by `refreshed`.

If you mean a literal refresh / reload of the page without any posting, you can use javascript to store the value when it is changed and load that value when the page is refreshed / loaded. Your storing options vary from cookies and local storage on the visitors computer to server-side storage using ajax.

If you are talking about using previously saved / posted values when you load the same page at a later time, it's a different story, although the ajax approach would work as well there (might not be necessary though).

**Edit:** Based on your edit, you need to add `selected="selected"` to the previously selected option.

So in the loop that builds your select options (assuming a loop), you do something like:

```
foreach($options as $key => $value)    // the loop, if any...
{
  echo "<li value='{$key}'";
  if ($key == $_POST['def'])
  {
    echo ' selected="selected"';
  }
  echo ">{$value}</li>"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a sample:

```
<?php
    $cbo_sel = 'SELECTED="SELECTED"'; //to make an item selected, append this attribute to that <option> element

    $post_success = false; //becomes true only when the data submitted is processed successfully

    $name   = '';
    $email  = '';
    $grade  = '';

    $user_msg = ''; //holds the messages to the user

    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST')
    {
        //assigning the values
        $name   = isset($_POST['name']) ? trim($_POST['name']) : '';
        $email  = isset($_POST['email']) ? trim($_POST['email']) : '';
        $grade  = isset($_POST['grade']) ? trim($_POST['grade']) : '';

        //do validation here
        if($name == '') // && any_regex_if_needed
            $user_msg = "Where is your name ?";
        else if($email == '')
            $user_msg = "How am I gonna contact you ?";
        else if($grade == '')
            $user_msg = "Oh! Don't hide your grade from me !";
        else
        {
            //everything is okay.. now do your things here... like inserting this to database or calculating or mailing, etc...
            //...
            //...

            $user_msg = 'Success !';
            $post_success = true; //success
        }
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>Testing..</title></head>
<body>

    <div><?php echo $user_msg; ?></div>

    <form method="POST">
        Name: 
            <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo (!$post_success)?$name:''; ?>" /> <br />
        Email: 
            <input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo (!$post_success)?$email:''; ?>" /> <br />
        Grade: 
            <select name="grade">
                <option value="A" <?php echo ($grade=='A' && !$post_success)?$cbo_sel:''; ?>>A</option> <!-- if grade='A' and if the data submitted was not processed(because of failed validation), then display the value -->
                <option value="B" <?php echo ($grade=='B' && !$post_success)?$cbo_sel:''; ?>>B</option>
                <option value="C" <?php echo ($grade=='C' && !$post_success)?$cbo_sel:''; ?>>C</option>
                <option value="D" <?php echo ($grade=='D' && !$post_success)?$cbo_sel:''; ?>>D</option>
            </select>

            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here, I am hardcoding the options. So, in case of a lengthy dropdown with several items, use a loop and check the option, using an if statement.

Maybe this could be improved. I welcome all suggestions. :)